# Actualización de variables en tiempo real PHP Html5 JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, variables

estoy diseñando una web en la cual en un div se muestran a los 7 usuarios con mayor puntaje.
A los puntajes los obtengo de la base de datos y funciona perfecto, al igual que el mecanismo de ordenamiento (mayor puntaje: puesto1, menor puntaje: puesto7).
El problema es que necesito estar actualizando constantemente esta información, que proviene de un archivo php el cual trae a los puntajes y los guarda en variables, probé de todo y no logro obtener resultados, les adjunto los códigos:

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function rep(){
        $("#rankingpoints").load("ranking.php")
    }

    setInterval(rep(),1500);
    
</script>
```

En home.php (pagina donde se imprime todo) con respecto al div tengo lo siguiente (Lo tengo implementado en PHP por el hecho de que tengo que imprimir variables que vienen de la db)
Tengo un div el cual tiene como id ("rankinpoints") y contiene lo siguiente

```
include ("ranking.php");
echo
'<div class="rankingpoints" id="rankingpoints">
<img src="list-numbered.png" alt="">

<a href="" >1. '.$puesto1.'</a>
<a href="" >2. '.$puesto2.'</a>
<a href="" >3. '.$puesto3.'</a>
<a href="" >4. '.$puesto4.'</a>
<a href="" >5. '.$puesto5.'</a>
<a href="" >6. '.$puesto6.'</a>
<a href="" >7. '.$puesto7.'</a>

</div>';
```

En ranking.php tengo lo siguiente

```
<?php

require ("conex.php");

$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM usuario";

$datos2 = mysqli_query($con,$consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$ranking=array(7);

while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos2)){

array_push($ranking, $fila2["puntaje"]);

}


arsort($ranking);


$rankinguser=array(7);

$i=1;


while ($i<=7) {
$cons = "SELECT username FROM usuario WHERE puntaje = '$ranking[$i]'";
$dat = mysqli_query($con,$cons) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$f = mysqli_fetch_array($dat);
array_push($rankinguser,$f["username"]);
$i=$i+1;
}



$puesto1 = $rankinguser[1];
$puesto2 = $rankinguser[2];
$puesto3 = $rankinguser[3];
$puesto4 = $rankinguser[4];
$puesto5 = $rankinguser[5];
$puesto6 = $rankinguser[6];
$puesto7 = $rankinguser[7];


?>
```

Creo que la lógica para poder resolver esto es estar refrescando constantemente este código de ranking.php y lograr que desde home.php se vayan tomando los datos que ranking.php me va devolviendo, pero no puedo lograrlo.

Comment: Yo estos temas los trato con ajax, atrapo un json que me devuelve el php y lo represento con jquery, pero ojo! el servidor tiene que estar bien configurado si piensas tener muchos usuarios simultáneos (más de 100 el servidor puede crashear), por otro lado, decirte que ni ajax ni tu método es a tiempo real, para implementar algo a tiempo real solo se me ocurre tirar de nodejs o similar.

Comment: La unica forma de implementar tiempo real es por el uso de socket.

Comment: Puedes usar WebSockets, usar AJAX es antiproducente ya que enviará muchas peticiones al sevdior lo que ocasionaría que se sobrecargue y se caiga.